# Nhibernate; control over when Session Per Request is saved

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to develop a ***web forms*** application using NHibernate and the *Session Per Request* model. All the examples I've seen have an HTTPModule that create a session and transaction at the beging of each request and then commits the transaction and closes the session at the end of the request. I've got this working but I have some concerns.

The main concern is that objects are automatically saved to the database when the web request is finished. I'm not particularly pleased with this and would much prefer some way to take a more active approach to deciding what is actually saved when the request is finished. Is this possible with the Session Per Request approach?

Ideally I'd like for the interaction with the database to go something like this:

1. Retreive object from the database or create a new one
2. Modify it in some way
3. Call a save method on the object which validates that it's indeed ready to be commited to the database
4. Object gets saved to the database

I'm able to accomplish this if I *do not* use the Sessions Per Request model and wrap the interactions in a `using` session / `using` transaction blocks. The problem I ran into in taking this approach is that after the object is loaded from the database the session is closed an I am not able to utilize lazy loading. Most of the time that's okay but there are a few objects which have lists of other objects that then cannot be modified because, as stated, the session has been closed. I know I could eagerly load those objects but they don't always get used and I feel that in doing so I'm failing at utilizing NHibernate.

Is there some way to use the Session Per Request (or any other model, it seems like that one is the most common) which will allow me to utilize lazy loading AND provide me with a way to manually decide when an object is saved back to the database? Any code, tutorials, or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and you should be able to find examples of it. This is how I do it:

- Use session-per-request but do not start a transaction at the start of the request.
- Set ISession.FlushMode to Commit.
- Use individual transactions (occasionally multiple per session) as needed.
- At the end of the session, throw an exception if there's an active uncommitted transaction. If the session is dirty, flush it and log a warning.

With this approach, the session is open during the request lifetime so lazy loading works, but the transaction scope is limited as you see fit. In my opinion, using a transaction-per-request is a bad practice. Transactions should be compact and surround the data access code.

Be aware that if you use database assigned identifiers (identity columns in SQL Server), NHibernate may perform inserts outside of your transaction boundaries. And lazy loads can of course occur outside of transactions (you should use transactions for reads also).

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm trying to achieve. Do you happen to have any links to any resources or possibly some code snippets illustrating this approach?

Comment: I can throw something together later but the only major difference from the other session-per-request examples is that the transaction is not started when the session is created, instead transactions are started on using blocks in the code-behind or controller.

Comment: Okay, I think that's enough for me to go on then. With this approach do _you_ have save methods on your objects?

Comment: I use the ISession directly for get and save. Note that if you retrieve an object with NHibernate, changes will be saved when the transaction is committed without any additional code. I use the repository pattern for queries. Your business objects should not reference NHibernate or perform data access IMO.

Comment: Right, but only if the change is made within the `using` transaction block, correct? I agree about the business objects, I'm trying code this in such a way that the consumer of the business object has no idea where or how the information is being saved.

Comment: No, the change does not need to be made inside the transaction. It looks a little weird but the transaction using block can often just contain txn.Commit().

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting some unexpected results. I'm creating 2 objects and then setting some of their properties. If I call the save method on the first one it saves as expected. Then if I modify object ones properties and save object 2 all the changes are being committed even though I'm only session.Save(object2)?

Comment: That's an expected result. Save makes an object persistent, it doesn't perform a save operation. http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-9-manipulating-persistent-data#

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think I've got this working the way I want using a combo of the repository pattern and units of work.